# In Ubuntu, how to enter grub rescue mode when gettint error 17

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, grub2

I'm booting up a machine and I'm getting error 17 from Grub.

Is there any way to enter grub rescue mode without a live cd?
(this is a remote server that I have no access)

Comment: What access do you have? You must have some sort of access to be able to boot it and see the error message.

Comment: VNC to see the boot process

Comment: Is that a physical server? You can't be running a VNC server that early in the boot process. It sounds like something you'd see on a virtual server though.